# metric spaces and density

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Rudin *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*

**2.18 Definition**   Let *X* be a metric space. All points and sets mentioned below are understood to be elements and subsets of *X*.
.

.

.

(*j*) *E* is *dense* in *X* if every point of *X* is a limit point of *E*, or a point of *E* (or both).

Rudin does not offer any examples of this in the entire chapter.  I am trying to get an example in order to understand this.

If we let X:=${\mathbb R}$ , and E be a subset, say the interval I:=(a,b), with a=0 and b=1 for example. Then every point of E=I is a limit point?

Does this satisfy the definition? I could use some guidance.

Comment: We have $2 \in \mathbb{R}$, and $2$ is neither a point nor a limit point of $(0,1)$. So that interval is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working idea of "denseness" in your context -- with the usual metric in $\mathbb{R}$:

$E$ is dense in $X$ if $E$ plus it's limit points =$X$.

I believe you are confusing the issue of which set the limit points come from.

**Every point in $X$** needs to be in $E$ or a limit point of a sequence from $E$.

Comment: So if the closure of E is X we have E is dense in X?

Comment: It works in this context -- but you need more general definitions when working with other topologies.

Comment: Would a set be called perfect if it satisfied the density property? Is there such a relation between the two?

Comment: What density property are you referring to? A set is perfect -- in this context -- if it is closed and contains no isolated points. You may not have closedness if a set is dense. Consider the set of irrational numbers,

Comment: Also you will see these definitions in a different light when you apply them to other topologies -- a lot of the underlying differences do not present themselves when working with $\mathbb{R}$ under the usual metric.

Comment: I am uncertain whether you have worked through/seen baby Rudin. Assuming your familiarity, will I be presented with varying situations that will bring these differences to light?

Comment: That depends on your instructor I'm afraid. When I worked through Baby Rudin, I couldn't see the point of these differences and definitions. But if you go on to study topology in general, these will be important.